# Using a hyperlink in a dotnetnuke 5 module

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am creating a dnn 5 module to extend an existing website. Everything has gone pretty well so far, but I cannot figure out how to link to another file inside my module.

Currently I have 2 files and their code behinds:

- View.ascx

  - View.ascx.cs
- EditMaintenance.ascx

  - EditMainenance.ascx.cs

In View.ascx I have added this line:

`<asp:HyperLink ID="linkToEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit Page" NavigateUrl="EditMaintenance.ascx" />`

However, when I click this link I am greeted with the following error:

`HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.`

**How do I create a link to that file?**

Comment: Isn't `.ascx` a user control?  User controls by themselves can't be served as pages, hence the configuration to deny such requests.  Why are you trying to navigate to a user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David is right.  Since it's a user control, you'll have to pass the full url, including the query string, into the NavigateUrl property.

Check this out:  http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/loc/print/page/module-navigation